Tensor of Tate module
Thanks for your reading. Let $E$ be a elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$. Could I know how to prove $T_p(E) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p} \mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p=E[p^\infty]$? I know $T_p(E)$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}_p-$module and I try to derive the result from the short exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p \rightarrow 0,
$$
or communtativity of tensor and inverse limit. Could I find some help. Thanks very much.

Note that tensor products do not commute with inverse limits in general. For example, $\mathbb Z_p\otimes \mathbb Q = \mathbb Q_p$, but $\varprojlim_n(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z\otimes \mathbb Q) = 0$.

@Mathmo123 Thanks very much. There is an answer give us some condition when it is true. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181004/inverse-limit-of-modules-and-tensor-product

First of all, note that $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb Z_p\simeq\varinjlim_n\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$, so the tensor product is
$$T_p(E)\otimes_{\mathbb Z_p}\varinjlim_n\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z.$$
Since tensor products commute with direct limits, this becomes
$$\varinjlim_n(T_p(E)\otimes \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z).$$
By construction, $T_p(E)\otimes \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z = T_p(E)/p^nT_p(E) = E[p^n]$, so the tensor product finally becomes
$$\varinjlim_nE[p^n],$$
which is exactly $E[p^\infty]$.

+1. For those, like me, who didn't know of the interpretation of $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$ as a direct limit: Viewing $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$ as a direct limit.

Thanks very much. The only question I have is that the tensor product is for $\mathbb{Z}p$, so we should have $T_p(E)\otimes{\mathbb{Z}p} \varinjlim\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}= \varinjlim (T_p(E)\otimes{\mathbb{Z}p}\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z})$, thus we need $T_p(E) \otimes{\mathbb{Z}_p} \mathbb{Z} / p^n \mathbb{Z}=T_p(E) / p^n T_p(E)=E\left[p^n\right]$ isn't it? Why is it right for $\mathbb{Z}_p$-modules? Or orignially we need use $\mathbb{Q}_p / \mathbb{Z}_p \simeq \varinjlim \mathbb{Z}_p / p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$?

You can view everything in sight as a $\mathbb Z_p$-module. Just as any abelian group naturally has the structure of a $\mathbb Z$-module, any abelian pro-$p$-group has the structure of a $\mathbb Z_p$-module.

@Mathmo123 So here I should regard $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module?

To make sense of these tensor products, yes.
