# In Kunneth Formula for Cohomology, the finitely generated condition is necessary.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, tensor-products, direct-product

> *Kunneth formula for cohomology: The cross product $H^*(X;\mathbb Z)\otimes H^*(Y;\mathbb Z)\to H^*(X\times Y;\mathbb Z)$ is an isomoprhism of rings if $X$ and $Y$ are CW complexes and $H^k(Y,R)$ is finitely generated free $R$-module for all $k$*.

To see the necessity of finitely generated condition, Hatcher gives an counterexample in the exercise of his *Algebraic Topology* section 3.2, is to take $X,Y$ to be infinite discrete sets, the cross product map $H^*(X;\mathbb Z)\otimes H^*(Y;\mathbb Z)\to H^*(X\times Y;\mathbb Z)$ is not an isomorphism.

In particular, the cross product is not isomorphic in the $0$-th cohomology. To prove this, since $X$ has infinite components, $H_0(X)\cong \bigoplus_{i\in I} \mathbb Z$, and by Universal coefficient theorem, $H^0$ is dual of $H_0$, so $H^0(X)\cong (H_0(X))^*\cong \prod_{i\in I}Z$. It is same for $Y$. Now it reduces to show the inclusion is not a surjective
$$\left(\prod_{i\in I}\mathbb Z\right) \otimes_{\mathbb Z}\left(\prod_{j\in J}\mathbb Z\right)\subsetneqq \prod_{(i,j)\in I\times J}\mathbb Z$$

for $I, J$ infinite sets, and the inclusion map is given by $$(n_i)_{i\in I}\otimes (m_j)_{j\in J}\mapsto (n_im_j)_{(i,j)\in I\times J}$$

In particular, since $$ \prod_{i\in I}\left(\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\left(\prod_{j\in J}\mathbb Z\right)\right)=\prod_{i\in I}\prod_{j\in J}\mathbb Z=\prod_{(i,j)\in I\times J}\mathbb Z$$

we just need to show $$\left(\prod_{i\in I}\mathbb Z\right) \otimes_{\mathbb Z}\left(\prod_{j\in J}\mathbb Z\right)\subsetneqq \prod_{i\in I}\left(\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\left(\prod_{j\in J}\mathbb Z\right)\right)$$

Or in other words, we just need in this case, commuting direct product and tensor product does not give you a surjective map. But I have no idea how to go on here.

I know there is a post :[Examples proving why the tensor product does not distribute over direct products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118790/examples-proving-why-the-tensor-product-does-not-distribute-over-direct-products) shows in general tensor product does not commutes with direct product. But, it does not help the special case I want to prove. Thanks in advance someone can help.

Comment: There is no need to invoke the Universal Coefficient Theorem to compute $H^0$ of a discrete space! It follows from a trivial computation using the singular complex, for example/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a natural isomorphism $$\prod_{I\times J}\mathbb{Z}\cong\operatorname{Hom}\left(\bigoplus_I\mathbb{Z},\prod_J\mathbb{Z}\right),$$ since Hom turns direct sums in the domain coordinate into direct products.  Every element of $\prod_I\mathbb{Z}\otimes \prod_J\mathbb{Z}$ then corresponds to a homomorphism $\bigoplus_I\mathbb{Z}\to\prod_J\mathbb{Z}$ whose image is finitely generated.  Indeed, an element $a\otimes b\in\prod_I\mathbb{Z}\otimes \prod_J\mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to the homomorphism that takes $c\in\bigoplus_I\mathbb{Z}$ to $(a\cdot c)b$ (where $a\cdot c=\sum_{i\in I} a_ic_i\in\mathbb{Z}$), and the image of this homomorphism is contained entirely in the subgroup generated by $b$.  So if you have a general element $$x=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\otimes b_k\in \prod_I\mathbb{Z}\otimes \prod_J\mathbb{Z},$$ the image of the homomorphism corresponding to $x$ is contained in the subgroup generated by $b_1,\dots,b_n$.  (Conversely, with a bit more work you can show that *every* homomorphism whose image is finitely generated comes from an element of the tensor product.)

Since $I$ and $J$ are both infinite, there exists a homomorphism $\bigoplus_I\mathbb{Z}\to\prod_J\mathbb{Z}$ whose image is not finitely generated (for instance, corresponding to any map $I\to J$ with infinite image).  Any such homomorphism gives an element of $\prod_{I\times J}\mathbb{Z}$ that is not in the image of $\prod_I\mathbb{Z}\otimes \prod_J\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What is the natural isomorphism which you mention at the beginnig of your answer.